# How to iterate over each Charset in java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

Tags: java

I am writing a Java test class and would like to iterate over all the Charsets specified in the [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class and specify each encoding when performing the .getBytes() on the myString variable.

I want to try something like this:

```
String myString = "Some Junk";

for (Charset encoding : StandardCharsets) {

    System.out.println("Using Encoding: " + encoding.displayName());
    byte[] newBytes = myString.getBytes(encoding);

    for (byte b : newBytes ) {
        System.out.print(b + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Obviously that is not correct.  Short of doing each one manually how can I step through all the Charsets defined in the [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class?

Comment: You'll have to construct a collection manually.

Comment: Do you want only the standard ones or all available ones? You can do `Charset.availableCharsets().values()` to get all the available ones on your system.

Comment: You could also use reflection, and specially `StandardCharsets.class.getDeclaredFields()` and then filter them based on which ones are public, static, final, and have type Charset. (That has the advantage of automatically picking up any new ones, if they get added — though that's unlikely.)

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to do, because for most of the things that I could think of using just 1-3 of these would solve the majority of the issues. Since, for example, there are 3 UTF-16 variants, which produce extremely similar output in your code, there's little value in using all 3. This feels like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I understand what you are saying Joachim, and you are correct I don't need every different Charset.  However, I thouht it would be good to see if there are any differences in the results without having to know each different charset in detail.  So as I mentioned a simply test class (not one that will be run anywhere/anytime other than on my machine and for my interest).  I was just wondering how I would step through each Charset defined in that StandardCharsets class.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your suggestions I came up with this which works (and probably can/should be improved on)

```
String myString = "Some Junk";

for (Field charSet : StandardCharsets.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            
    String encoding = charSet.getName();

    //This is because the Charsets in StandardCharsets all use underscores however
    //when passing the string to .getBytes() you need to pass UTF-8 and not UTF_8
    //** All except for ISO_8859_1 ** - Sigh I wish I could do this better.
    if (encoding.startsWith("U")) { 
        encoding = encoding.replaceAll("_", "-");
    }
    System.out.println("Using Encoding: " + encoding);
            
    byte[] newByteStr = myString.getBytes(Charset.forName(encoding));               
    for (byte b : newByteStr ) {
        System.out.print(b + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println("");
}
```

This will convert the string in myString to a byte array with the relevant encoding of every Charset found in StandardCharSets.  Which is what I wanted in the end.

**EDIT 1:** So based on MC Emperor's comment I now have this

```java
String myString = "Some Junk";

for (Field field: StandardCharsets.class.getDeclaredFields()) {

    if (field.get(null) instanceof Charset charset) { 
        System.out.println("Using Encoding: " + charset.displayName());
                
        byte[] newByteStr = myString.getBytes(charset);               
        for (byte b : newByteStr ) {
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This seems far better as I no longer have to use string replacements.

Comment: Well, you are better off using the actual `Charset` instead of its string representation. If you wrap the code in a `if (field.get(null) instanceof Charset charset) { }` block, you have access to the `charset` variable, which can be used instead of `String encoding`.